# Excel BOM Item Low Level

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Based on the simplified list of parent and child items how can I obtain the low level each item as per column F. Happy cosider either a formula or vba solution.

[image]

Comment: Is there something in cols A and B that cause Item M to have a Low Level = 3?

Comment: I don't see how you're getting those numbers fam

Comment: To clarify M is level 3 as M is a child of L, L is a child of H and H is a child of A or E. As A or E are not children of any items then their level is zero then M is level 3.

Comment: Item L is a child of D which would make it level 1 but because L is also a child of H and H is a child of A or E then the lowest level for L is 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put the following vba to find the low level for items which works independent so initial sort order. The low level for each item is shown in column C and I intend to copy and remove duplicates to obtain a concise list. Just need to find a way to identify when its time to stop the loop.

[image]

```
Sub setlowlevel()

Dim lowlevel As Integer
Dim StartRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

'Find lowlevels
lowlevel = 0
StartRow = 2
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Do

Sheet4.Range("C" & StartRow).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTIF(R" & StartRow & "C2:R" & LastRow & "C2,RC[-2])=0," & lowlevel & "," & lowlevel + 1 & ")"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C" & StartRow & ":C" & LastRow)


    Range("A" & StartRow & ":C" & LastRow).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C" & StartRow & ":C" & LastRow) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A" & StartRow & ":C" & LastRow)
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

lowlevel = lowlevel + 1
StartRow = Sheet4.Range("C:C").Find(what:=lowlevel, after:=Sheet4.Range("C1"), LookIn:=xlValues).Row

Loop Until ???????????

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data is always in the format you have shown with the lowest rank item first, could you use a Vlookup?

=vlookup(E2,A:B,2,false)

This would pull the item to the right of A at the first occurrence of A.  If you need the last item then you could use:

=vlookup(E2,A:B,2,true)